# Got error while migrating to Android Studio 3.1 Canary 5 Build?

Tags: android, maven, android-gradle-plugin, jetbrains-ide, migrate

I tried following steps:

1.changed to 
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0-alpha05'

2. maven {
           url 'https://maven.google.com/'
           name 'Google'
       }

   and added google()
3. android.enableAapt2=false in gradle.properties

4.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.thehomesalon"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 6
        versionName "3.2"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        lintOptions {

            checkReleaseBuilds false

        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug
                {

                }
    }

    flavorDimensions "default"
}
```

5. changed to implementation from compile.

Please Help if any one gone through same issue..

[image: please click for error]

Comment: Please post your stacktrace in your question as if the image gets taken down or is deleted, it will be hard for others to get what your stacktrace is.

Comment: Please check i was editing  image only.